# ng test is not working after angular14 ugrade

Tags: angular, angular14, karma-webpack

I am receiving below error while I ran ng test after Angular14 Upgrade.:

[image]

I got the the below post and removed the context from my **test.ts** file, and getting below error[image]

**angular.json:**

```
"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:karma",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.ng.config.js",
              "mergeStrategies": {
                "externals": "replace"
              }
            },
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "main": "client/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "client/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [              
              "client/styles.less"
            ]
            }
```